# Find Closest Number to Zero

Tags: java, arrays

I used this approach but it is not working on input like
[1,1,-1].When ever -1 comes after 1 in arrays it is showing wrong answer.

> Problem statement to the question is
> Given an integer array nums of size n, return the number with the value closest to 0 in nums. If there are multiple answers, return the number with the largest value.

```
class Solution {
    public int findClosestNumber(int[] nums) {
        int minDiff=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int ans=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            if(Math.abs(nums[i])<minDiff)
            {
                minDiff=Math.abs(nums[i]);
                ans=i;
            }else if(Math.abs(nums[i])==minDiff)
            {
                ans=Math.max(ans,i);
            }
        }
        return nums[ans];
    }
}
```

Comment: `ans=Math.max(ans,i)`  The problem here is that `ans` and `i` are not the integers themselves.  They're the *indexes* of the integers within `nums`.

Comment: I agree with slothrop. You could do if (nums[i] > 0) ans=i

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just update the `else if` condition:

```
else if(Math.abs(nums[i])==minDiff)
{
    ans=Math.max(ans,i);
}
```

like this:

```
     else if(Math.abs(nums[i])==minDiff)
     {
          ans=nums[ans] > nums[i] ? ans : i;
     }
```

compare the value at indexes, rather than comparing indexes.